# Ayuda para cambiar de imágen al hacer click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo el siguiente código *HTML*.

```
<body ng-app="Game">
<nav class="navbar" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <img src="resources/images/play-symbol.png" class="play-symbol pointer"/>
</nav>
```

... y quiero que **estas imágenes cambien entre sí** cuando se haga click, así que añadí el siguiente código *jQuery*:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".play-symbol").click(function(){
  $(".play-symbol").replaceWith("<img src='resources/images/pause-symbol.png' class='pause-symbol pointer'/>");
});

$(".pause-symbol").click(function(){
  $(".pause-symbol").replaceWith("<img src='resources/images/play-symbol.png' class='play-symbol pointer'/>");
});    });
```

Cuando hago click en la primera imagen (play), cambia a la de pausa, pero después vuelvo a dar click y no vuelve a cambiar. Todos mis enlaces y nombres en *CSS* están correctos.

Comment: Has de hacer lapregunta en español. esta es la pagina española

Comment: Perdón, creía que todo el mundo podría verla y lo puse en inglés para que me respondiesen lo antes posible

Comment: No pasa nada, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! pasa por el tour para aprender como funciona todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no entiendo por que si usas Angular haces el cambio de la imagen con jQuery, en Angular puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ["$scope",function($scope) {
    $scope.src = 'resources/images/pause-symbol.png';
    $scope.pause = false;
    $scope.changeImage = function(argument) {
        if ($scope.pause) {
            $scope.img = 'resources/images/play-symbol.png';
        }else{
            $scope.img = 'resources/images/pause-symbol.png';
        }
        $scope.pause = !$scope.pause;

    };
}]);
```

y el html

```
<body ng-app="Game">
 <nav class="navbar" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <img ng-src="{{src}}" class="play-symbol pointer" ng-click="changeImage()"/>
</nav>
```

Por otro lado si insistes en hacerlo en jQuery, el error sucede por que amarras el evento click a un elemento que remplazas, entonces el elemento deja de existir por lo tanto también el evento amarrado, para que funcione debes colocar tu javascript de la siguiente forma

```
$(document).on('click','.play-symbol',function(event) {
    $(".play-symbol").replaceWith("<img src='resources/images/pause-symbol.png' class='pause-symbol pointer'/>");
});
$(document).on('click','.pause-symbol',function(event) {
    $(".pause-symbol").replaceWith("<img src='resources/images/play-symbol.png' class='play-symbol pointer'/>");
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, utilizo jQuery en vez de Angular porque todavía estoy aprendiendo a usar Angular y no todas sus funciones.